# 'Request' object has no attribute 'get' error using graphene python when running mutations in Insomnia

Tags: graphene-python

I just started using Graphene SQLAlchemy.  I have followed the graphene documentation to a T and successfully created my GraphQL server and my queries are fine.  I went on and worked on my mutations but due to lack of documentation and support for SQLAlchemy, I managed to find an excellent resource (as per [link](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/issues/29))

I have successfully integrated this [gist](https://gist.github.com/flewellyn/a655fb480abc24c6929385257286c3e5) and when I tested using Insomnia, I got this error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "'Request' object has no attribute 'get'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "addCalendarYear": null
    }
}
```

My model:

```
@dataclass
class UtilsFields():
    priority = Column(Integer, default=0)
    isSynced = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    isDeleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)

@dataclass
class CalendarYear(Base, UtilsFields):
    __tablename__ = 'tblCalendarYears'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    year = Column(String(4))
```

Here's my sub schema that I've used for my mutation:

```
@dataclass
class UtilsAttributes():

    priority = graphene.Int(default_value=0)
    isSynced = graphene.Boolean(default_value=False)
    isDeleted = graphene.Boolean(default_value=False)


class CalendarYear(SQLAlchemyObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarYearModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class AddCalendarYearInput(SQLAlchemyInputObjectType, UtilsAttributes):

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarYearModel

    year = graphene.String(default_value='')


class AddCalendarYear(SQLAlchemyMutation):

    class Arguments:
        input = graphene.Argument(AddCalendarYearInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarYearModel
        create = True

    Output = CalendarYear
```

and a main schema:

```
class Mutate(graphene.ObjectType):
    from my_schemas.calendarSchema import AddCalendarYear

    addCalendarYear = AddCalendarYear.Field()


db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autocommit=False,
        autoflush=False,
        bind=engine
    )
)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

schema = graphene.Schema(
            query=Query,
            mutation=Mutate,
            types=[
                CalendarYear
            ]
        )

schema.execute(context_value={'session': db_session})
```

and here's my mutation in Insomnia:

```
mutation addYear {
    addCalendarYear(input: {year: "2018"}) {    
        priority
        year
        isSynced
        isDeleted
    }
}
```

I wonder if I missed anything.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  TIA.